# Count positives from float vector using _mm_cmpgt_pd

Tags: c++, c, sse, intrinsics

I'm trying to make a program using  intrinsics that counts the >0 elements of a float vector,

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Want exotica answer or practical fastest code?

Comment: Do you want strictly greater than `0.0`, or would it be ok to count non-negative by counting elements with their sign bit cleared?  Actually, you could count negative elements and subtract from the total count, if it's ok to count `-0.0` as negative.  (It might be possible to go faster than `cmpgt_pd` by using integer pack instructions like Harold's answer, but on the FP bit patterns instead of compare results, to narrow while preserving the sign bit.)

Comment: `float *pointer = (float*)&destination;` ???  You're treating a vector of two 64-bit elements of all-zero bits (`(double)0.0` or all-one bits (double `NaN`) as `float`?)

Comment: C and C++ are not the same language. Which are you using?